# Syntax error in UPDATE statement while updating password in Access database

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, syntax-error, ms-access-2010

I faced syntax error in UPDATE statement, while updating password in Access database in C#:

```cs
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection();
    con.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" +
        Server.MapPath("~/Database/registration.accdb");

    con.Open();

    OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand();
    cmd.Connection = con;
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    cmd.CommandText =
        "UPDATE into userdata(password)values('"+TextBox1.Text+"') where id=@id";
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    con.Close();
    Response.Write("alert('Password Reset Successfully done');"); 
}
```

Comment: So, what exactly is your question?

Comment: Where is the syntax error?

Comment: You need to learn about the syntax of UPDATE SQL statement... `UPDATE INTO` is not the correct syntax

Comment: Also, you are passing parameters as a mix of string concatenation for the text and command parameter (`@id`) for the id, but you are never setting this parameter. With OLEDB you must specify the parameters as `?`. Use command parameters for both of your inputs. See: [OleDbCommand.Parameters Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.oledb.oledbcommand.parameters?view=dotnet-plat-ext-5.0) for an example. And use either an [INSERT](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10941284/880990) or an [UPDATE](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29534671/880990) command, not a mix of both.

Comment: And finally _password_ is a reserved word for an Access Sql Engine. You need to put it between square brackets.

Comment: And, storing a password in a database is a complete no-no.  NEVER NEVER NEVER store an unhashed password (not even encrypted).

Comment: please use ***parameterised queries*** - building SQL queries by concatenation etc. is a recipe for disaster. not only is it a source for many hard to debug syntax errors, it's also a wide, open gate for ***[SQL Injection attacks](https://bobby-tables.com/)***.

Comment: When using parameterized queries in OLEDB, parameter names aren't honored in the SQL text. Therefore, the order that the parameters are added is important. When using parameters, if a column name occurs more than once in the SQL, then it must be added more than once as a parameter (and in the order it occurs in the SQL).

Comment: You should also have your connection and command objects in `using` blocks

Comment: I casted a reopen vote because the marked as duplicates ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1054022/best-way-to-store-password-in-database), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14376473/what-are-good-ways-to-prevent-sql-injection)) are about storing passwords in databases, while this question's relevance with passwords is only accidental. The OP could attempt to update any kind of tables/columns, and they would have the same problem.

Answer (score 3):

It's because your `SQL Query` is not correct, that's not how you update data in your database. It should be like this:

```
query = "Update [tableName] SET [ColumnName] = 'Values', [ColumnName1] = 'Values2',...";
```

You should learn at least the basics of SQL syntax, more information [here](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_update.asp)

And also, you shouldn't concatenate your query since it will become vulnerable for `SQL Injection attack`, you should at least use `Parameterized Query`

```
OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection();
con.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" +
    Server.MapPath("~/Database/registration.accdb");

con.Open();

OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand();
cmd.Connection = con;
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
cmd.CommandText =
    "UPDATE yourTableName SET [yourColumnName] = @YourFirstValue, [secondColumnName] = @YourSecondValue WHERE [columnKey] = @ID"

cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@YourFirstValues", textbox1.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@YourSecondValue ", textbox2.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", textbox3.Text);

cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
con.Close();
Response.Write("alert('Password Reset Successfully done');");
```

Comment: @user9938 A textbox can't have the value of `null`. And the value of empty will work fine, despite your assertion.

Answer (score 1):

you have to fix your query

```
   "UPDATE  userdata SET password=@password where id=@id";
```

and add  new lines before  cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", id);
 cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password", TextBox1.Text);
```

Comment: Will probaby work, but: **NEVER** store passwords in the database. Use salted hashes instead.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, it gave me a syntax error that I solved by checking the whole string and actually there was a comma too many, I don't know if this answer of mine can be useful, among other things after some time.